# Why does the default value of an empty list have 2 empty index when making class list

Tags: python

I tried making this class list and when I call the len(class) it returns 2 instead of 0.

I debug and found that the default value for the arr is 2 Nonetype items.
I don't know the right terms but here is the code.

```
Class Cars:

    def __init__(self, arr=[]): # arr has len of 2 for some reason
        self.Cars = arr
        self.size = len(arr)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size
```

Call:

```
my_cars = Cars()
len(class) # == 2
```

Comment: Can you post a working code example? `class` is a reserved word in Python so it is unclear to me how to even run `class = Class()`. Maybe I should add that if I change `class` to some other variable name, I find that the `len` is 0, which is not what you are observing.

Comment: almost certainly because the default argument is getting re-used, but you must provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening becaue you are declaring your default list in the wrong way. When you declare a default list as an argument then that same list will be used everytime you call the function, it wont create a new list as you expected.

Here's an article that explains this in greater detail [Common Python Cotchas](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/).

So the right way to declare a default list or any mutable object would be like this:

```py
def __init__(self, arr=None):
    if arr is None:
        arr = []
    self.Class = arr
    self.size = len(arr)
```

This way you create a new list every time the function is called as expected.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use `class` for a variable

It's a reserved word in Python. Changing `class` to `my_class` I have the length at 0

### You could try with this code (modified from yours)

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arr=[]):
        self.Class = arr
        self.size = len(arr)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size


my_class = Test()
print(len(my_class))
```